# Include directives order in source file and in header file

Tags: c++, include, cpp-core-guidelines

Which is the recommended order in which the `#include` directives are supposed to be listed? I could not find any answer in the **C++ Core Guidelines**

For example, should they be ordered like this:

```
#include "OtherHeaderInCurrentLib.h"
#include <third_party_library/header.h>
#include <iostream>
```

Or should they be ordered like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <third_party_library/header.h>
#include "OtherHeaderInCurrentLib.h"
```

And is there any difference between the recommended ordering when they are listed inside a source files and when they are listed inside a header files?

Comment: Alphabetically sounds sound

Comment: I think if your headers include everything that they need this is mostly user preference.

Comment: @drescherjm I doubt since language features such as ADL heavily rely on the declaration order, which can rely on the inclusion order.

Comment: _"I doubt since language features such as ADL heavily rely on the declaration order"_ This is a clear sign, that these headers are written in a wrong way. The order shouldn't matter at all. The client should only `#include` what's actually needed.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you have an example for order of inclusion matters for ADL (even though each header includes what they use) ?

Comment: For me working with precompiled headers on msvc (for 2+ decades) it behaves much like your second example for source files. I mean inside the pch.h I usually include the system headers and probably the third party headers but  then have to include the pch.h as your first include since that is a requirement for your source files as the precompiled header implementation has the compiler ignoring all lines above `#include "pch.h"`

Comment: This is destined for an opinion-close, but I'm gonna give mine. Put yours first. It greatly assists in avoiding consumption-based inclusion dependencies. I.e. If your header requires `<string>`, it should include `<string>`. If you don't, but put it last after a stack of includes in a cpp that has `#include <string>`, that mishap is hidden... until you use it somewhere else where the consuming cpp didn't include `<string>` before your header, and now you're wondering wtf.. this worked before, why not now?  In short, I agree with eerorika.

Comment: @WhozCraig not my intention, I though there would be some more stable guidelines about this topic, but yeah, it looks like my question has struck the Stack Overflow Undefined Behavior. In the end most of the C++ Core Guidelines can be seen as opinions, but there are usually reasons behind those recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

A disadvantage of including standard, or third party headers before first party custom headers is that it will be very easy to accidentally depend on headers which you forgot to include directly. This will cause problems when the indirect inclusion is removed due to unrelated changes, or the custom header is included into context that doesn't have that missing dependency.

In the typical x.hpp, x.cpp "module" structure (not to be confused with C++20 modules), including x.hpp as the first header in x.cpp ensures that all such headers will have at least one translation unit where they are included first, avoiding the problem of undetected missing inclusions within x.hpp.

Other than that, it is a good idea to keep the inclusions in order so that it is easy to see what the dependencies are at a glance. Grouping by library, and sorting groups alphabetically are typical ways to keep the inclusions in order.

Comment: fwiw, google guideline recommends to put your projects headers last: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes arguing that putting `foo.h` first in `foo.cpp` is sufficient to make it break in case of missing includes while others using `foo.h` shouldnt be bothered with the error.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 this is what I was looking for, some industry standard recommendation with reasons behind the choice. Unfortunately, as always they have to rush the close of any question to get their beloved tokens, otherwise I would have chosen your answer.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 That's a reasonable argument. They seem to not explain why it would be advantageous to include rest of the custom headers after the standard headers though. As far as I can tell, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 It's not an industry standard. It's a Google style guide.

Comment: @nyarlthotep108 yes consider that the google guideline was written with a very specific code base in mind. Its different problems you face when you have to manage millions of lines of code somehow. Once in a while I find a bullet point in their guideline, that I simply do not want to apply in my projects (but I understand why they put it in their guideline)